# NFA that ends with 0 and doesn't have 11 after the first 0

Tags: finite-automata

So as the title says i m trying to find this NFA. So far i thought to make an NFA that "guesses" what comes after the first 0 and i got this: [image]

After some time trying to get rid of all the extra (7 !) states i put in i got to this beauty: [image]

But now i cant figure out how to get rid of the one extra state. Also if you have any tips on how to go to simpler NFA's instead of what i did (like a thought process for this problem) i would appreciate it a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove state 2, and make a transition from 1 to 5 directly. This will get rid both of a state (state 2) and a connection (the epsilon connection)

Comment: Thank you, it was really simple indeed but i didn't see it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

From the theoretical perspective: there is a [completely algorithmic procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) that given a DFA returns an equivalent DFA with the minimum number of states.

In your specific case: remove the $\epsilon$ transition and merge state $2$ with state $5$.

Comment: i know of the DFA algorithm, but we arent taught the NFA one. Thanks for your help

Comment: There is also an [algorithmic construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to convert any NFA into a DFA. Apply this first, then minimize the resulting DFA.

Comment: Although in this specific example, its required to find a minimal NFA, and converting it into a DFA will just increase it's size overall (even if you try to minimize it later)

Comment: There is no known efficient algorithm to convert a DFA to an equivalent minimal NFA. In fact this problem is [PSPACE-hard](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-54233-7_169). An algorithm in PSPACE is the following: minimize your DFA and let $n$ be the number of states of the resulting DFA. Consider all the (at most $(|\Sigma|+1)^{(n-1)(n-2)} \cdot 2(n-1)^2$) NFAs with up to $n-1$ states (guess the transitions, the number of final states and whether the initial state is final). Check if the language accepted by any of them matches the language of your DFA (this is in P).